# How do I use all cores when building in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I just tried to [compile Unreal Engine](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/ProductionPipelines/DevelopmentSetup/BuildingUnrealEngine/index.html) as documented by Epic Games.

While building the project in Visual Studio 2017, I noticed that most of my cores are idle:

[image]

Even if I subtract the cores that are only logic (because they are not "real"), half of the cores are more or less inactive. (16 real cores, but only 6-8 of them seem to be really working)

I doubt that other hardware components are a bottleneck. The memory is half-empty and the SSD's are doing basically nothing (arround 1% usage).
I've set the *maximum number of parallel project builds* in the Visual Studio settings to 32.

Is there something I've been missing? Can I do something to get better performance by utilizing more cores?

Comment: I get this output in the middle of my build, clearly not using all the cores that I'm expecting...
```
`8>Determining max actions to execute in parallel (16 physical cores, 32 logical cores)`
`8>  Executing up to 16 processes, one per physical core`
`8>Building 5651 actions with 16 processes...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all operations/algorithms  are equally suitable for parallelization. Some are inherently sequential in nature.
e.g. the sequence in which different projects are built is dictated by the dependencies between them.
Furthermore A lot of intermediate files are used during compilation and building. Even when using SSD's, this involves a lot of IO-bound operations where the CPU-core idles. Since a lot of those files are small, they will not cause a lot of throughput but they will involve a significant overhead...

Maybe an interesting read: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19643/which-algorithms-can-not-be-parallelized

Comment: Interesting answer and thanks for the link. I have two questions about your answer: 1) According to your answer, I assume the only way to improve performance and reduce build time in this case would be more single core performance, is that correct? 2) Is there a visualization of IO-bound that is relevant to building in the task manager or somewhere else? A way to actually see that this is the bottleneck?

Comment: Different elements will have an impact: single core performance, memory speed, I/O-latency, structure of the compiler, specifics of the solution being built... But there are no magical single changes that on their own will determine the build time.
Some things you can try: use a RAM-disk: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071194/change-visual-studio-build-path-for-ram-disk
and an old one (still relevant, I think): https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/02/building-your-project-should-be-pretty-quick/